# How do I convert from ICONDIR to GRPICONDIR?

Tags: delphi, winapi, resources, icons

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101018-00/?p=12513) we have a clear and authoritative explanation of the structure of an icon file and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120720-00/?p=7083) he explains how it differs from how the same icons are stored as resources.

The code below is intended to do an resource update for icons and very nearly does because it *does* update all the actual icons, I can check in Resource Hacker and see that they're all there. But somehow I'm mangling the directory. When you do that, the resource compiler is infuriatingly acquiescent and just sticks in a bunch of default values. It *can* tell how many icons there are, but it claims they're all 16 x 16 and won't display them, and what actually shows up in Explorer as the icon is a default picture of a Windows form.

I'm at a loss. What I'm trying to do here seems easy and yet is not happening. Am I overlooking some subtle point or having a massive attack of the dumb? Any help would be gratefully received.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var   vResHandle: THandle;
      MyIcon: TMemoryStream;

      i,j: integer;
      s: string;
      ImageCount: Word;
      ImageSize: DWord;
      ab, m: TMemoryStream;

const HeaderSize = 6;
      IcoEntrySize = 16;
      ResEntrySize = 14;

begin

// Short explanation. An icon file consists of (a) a six-byte header which
// includes among other things information about how many icons are in
// the file; (b) sixteen bytes of metadata for each icon; (c) the icons.

// But that's how icons are stored as files. As executable resources,
// Windows considers that (a) and (b) are one resource but (c) is a different
// resource, indeed one resource for each image, so we have to split the icon
// file up and do several resource updates.

// It also requires only fourteen bytes of metadata per entry: instead of the
// last parameter being a double word it's a single one. It doesn't matter
// what's in it if I have understood the guru aright, the resource compiler
// takes care of that for us, we're just leaving a space..

// Get the icon.
MyIcon := TMemoryStream.Create;
ab := TMemoryStream.Create;
m := TMemoryStream.Create;

MyIcon.LoadFromFile('icon.ico');

// Get the handle for the resource update..
vResHandle := BeginUpdateResource('test.exe', False);
// We skip to where Windows keeps the image count and read it.
MyIcon.Seek(4,soFromBeginning);
ImageCount:=MyIcon.ReadWord;

// Go back to the beginning ...
MyIcon.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);

for j:=1 to HeaderSize do ab.WriteByte(MyIcon.ReadByte);
for i:=1 to ImageCount do
    begin
    for j:=1 to IcoEntrySize - 4 do ab.WriteByte(MyIcon.ReadByte);
    MyIcon.ReadDWord;  // To skip over it.
    ab.WriteWord(0);
    end;

// We do a hex dump of ab:
ab.seek(0,soFromBeginning);
s:='';
for i:=1 to ab.Size do
    begin
    s:=s+IntToHex(ab.ReadByte,2)+' ';
    if (i - 6) mod 14 = 0 then s:=s + sLineBreak;
    end;
showmessage(s+'  Size: '+inttostr(ab.Size));

// Update the icon directory. This is the bit that doesn't work.
UpdateResource(vResHandle
                      , RT_GROUP_ICON
                      , PChar('MAINICON')
                      , LANG_NEUTRAL
                      , ab.Memory
                      , ab.Size);

// All the rest of it works as planned.

// Now the size of each icon is contained as a double word in the directory
// entries for each item, so we use that to cut the remainder of the memory
// stream into chunks and update them one at a time.

for i := 1 to ImageCount do
    begin
    m := TMemoryStream.Create;
    ab.Seek(HeaderSize+(i-1)*ResEntrySize+8,soFromBeginning);
    ImageSize:=ab.ReadDWord;
    for j:=1 to ImageSize do m.WriteByte(MyIcon.ReadByte);
    UpdateResource(vResHandle
                  , RT_ICON
                  , MAKEINTRESOURCE(i)
                  , LANG_NEUTRAL
                  , m.Memory
                  , m.Size);
    m.Free;
    end;

EndUpDateResource(vResHandle,False);
MyIcon.Free;
ab.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Your icon IDs in the directory entry are all "0". You should probably replace `ab.WriteWord(0);` with `ab.WriteWord(i);` since you later use (i) when writing individual icons.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thanks. I did try it but it didn't work and there are reasons why it shouldn't. First as I mentioned in the code, the guru says that these are filled in by the resource compiler. Second, if you use Resource Hacker or some similar utility to look at the data in a working icon resource the IDs don't start at 1 and they don't match up with the "ordinal names".

Comment: OK, new plan. I'll attach icon.ico to an application, find a way to extract its resource file into a memory stream, and then do a hex dump and see what that looks like. I don't know how to read a resource file, but it'll all be documented somewhere.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, my apologies you are quite right. The reason I didn't notice is that Windows Explorer is so tenacious in cache-ing this stuff that it doesn't change until you restart Explorer. Why didn't I know that, or guess it? Because that's not true if you upload a broken directory as I have just done so often, then it goes to the default icon immediately. What's weirder, if you then fix that by uploading a new perfectly-formed directory ... it goes back to displaying the original icon. The original one. You can see how I got confused. Anyway you are quite right and thank you again.